# Why does this regex return an empty list?

Tags: python, regex

New programmer here..
I am trying to get all of the hashtags and links from a string. The regular expressions return the desired result when on their own; however, an empty list is returned when they are combined. How can one fix this?

```
import re

tweet = ('New PyBites article: Module of the Week - Requests-cache '
     'for Repeated API Calls - http://pybit.es/requests-cache.html '
     '#python #APIs')


# Get all hashtags and links from tweet
def get_hashtags_and_links(tweet=tweet):
tweet_regex = re.compile(r'''(
                         \(#\w+\)
                         \(https://[^\s]+\)
                         )''', re.VERBOSE)

tweet_object = tweet_regex.findall(tweet)
print(tweet_object)

get_hashtags_and_links()
```

Comment: Without really analyzing the regex, you have a ton of whitespaces in it due to the indentation.

Comment: @DanielF thats the re.VERBOSE bit

Comment: plus parentheses, plus https vs http... you need to simplify the regex and the string first to be able to debug it

Comment: `\(` that is an actual parenthesis

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks! I didn't know that this exists, and it's so good to know.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for `#\w+`(enclosed in literal parenthesis) immediately followed by `https://[^\s]+`(also enclosed in literal parenthesis) which appears no where in your text

instead use the `|` or bar

```
re.compile(r'''(
            \(#\w+\)|
            \(https://[^\s]+\)
                     )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

but as pointed out `\(` is looking for an actual parenthesis (it is not grouping)

so you probably just want

```
"(#\w+)|(https?://[^\s]+)"
```

you can use non-capturing groups(`(?:...)`) if you want  as well

```
"((?:#\w+)|(?:https?://[^\s]+))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex as follows :

```
    http_hash_search = re.compile(r"(\w+:\/\/\S+)|(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)")
```

#[A-Za-z0-9]+ --- This will search for #hashtag followed by any number or letters

(\w+://\S+) --- This will search for paths on the tweets

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you wanted to search for with your regex, you need to make sure you escape `#` char that is special in case you compile the regex with [`re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X). This option enables *comments* inside the regex pattern that start with an unescaped hash symbol and go on till the line end.

> When a line contains a `#` that is not in a character class and is not
> preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost
> such `#` through the end of the line are ignored.

So, assuming you want to match either hashtags or specific URLs you may use

```
tweet_regex = re.compile(r'''
                     \#\w+             # Hashtag pattern
                     |                 # or
                     https?://\S+      # URLs
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

See the [Python code demo](https://ideone.com/jHJsF6), output:

```
['http://pybit.es/requests-cache.html', '#python', '#APIs']
```